# Como fazer para limpar um <p:messages> do form pelo Bean?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

**Eu tenho a seguinte situação:**
1. Tenho um xhtml com `<p:tabView>` com id="tab";
2. Nesta tabView tenho 3 abas e cada uma com seus forms e `<p:messages>` com respectivos id;

**Qual o problema?** Na aba 1 eu tenho o registro principal, nas demais são filhos deste registro e preciso exibir apenas quando um código é gerado. Até aqui tudo bem, tenho um atributo no bean booleano que verifica se o ID é diferente de "0" e nas abas estou usando o atributo "renderer".

Quando insiro o registro na aba principal e o ID é gerado, eu atualizo a tabView (id = tab) e no retorno do método informo ao usuário que o registro foi salvo.

**O problema!**
Quando atualizo a tab para que as abas seja exibidas, os `<p:messages>` de cada uma também é atualizado com a mensagem da aba principal.

Tem como eu limpar um componente pelo id através do Bean?

Toda ajuda será bem vinda!

Fragmento do Bean

```
        // define mensagem de sucesso
    messages.info("Atividade salva com sucesso!");

    // atualiza componentes na view
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset(":frmAtividade:tab:frmEnvolvidos:msg-envolvidos");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("frmAtividade:tab:aba1:msg-principal","frmAtividade:pnl-cabecalho",
            "frmAtividade:painel-responsavel","frmAtividade:tab"));
```

Fragmentos do xhtml

```
                    <p:tab title="Envolvidos" id="aba-envolvidos" rendered="#{cadastroAtividadeBean.abaEnvolvidos}" disabled="#{!cadastroAtividadeBean.abasAtivas}">
                    <h:form id="frmEnvolvidos" >
                        <p:messages id="msg-envolvidos" />
                        <p:toolbar id="toolbar-principal">
                            <f:facet name="left">
                                <p:commandLink value="Cancelar" title="Cancelar"
                                    action="#{cadastroAtividadeBean.cancelar()}"
                                    styleClass="btn btn-dark"
                                    immediate="true">
                                </p:commandLink>

                            </f:facet>
                        </p:toolbar>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("idDoComponente");`?

Comment: Weslley eu fiz a implementação **e não funcionou**. Veja eu fiz o reset depois de fazer o update nos demais componentes. Existe precedência nestas chamadas?

Comment: Você pode postar o seu código?

Comment: Complementei a questão com fragmentos do bean e o xhtml

Comment: Coloque o reset no final do seu método.

Comment: Coloquei e mesmo assim a mensagem continua sendo exibida.